# Rails form_for using wrong action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, put, form-for, controllers

I am using rails 3.2.8 and I am having an issue with form_for:

I have the following form within the view of a different model:

```
<%= form_for pair, { :method => :put } do |f| %>
     <td><%= pair.token.value %></td>
     <td><%= pair.pair_token.value %></td>
     <td><%= pair.freq %></td>
     <td><%= pair.distance %></td>
     <td><%= f.select :distance, [['', nil], ['Strongly Opposite', -3], ['Moderately Opposite', -2], ['Weakly Opposite', -1],
                              ['No Relationship', 0], ['Weakly Similar', 1], ['Moderately Similar', 2], ['Strongly Similar', 3]], {}, {} %></td>
     <td><%= pair.agree %></td>
     <td><%= f.select :agree, [['', nil],['True', 1], ['False', 0]], {}, {} %></td>
     <td><%= f.submit %></td>
<% end %>
```

This form is within the view for a model called tokens.  The page is actually the tokens show.html.  I am getting the response:

```
No route matches [POST] "/pairs/269671"
```

I am not sure what is going wrong as I am asking for the  PUT action and the pair object is trying to do a post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What does your routes file look like?

Rails has default HTTP verbs that it uses for different actions. See here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Create happens via POST, and update happens via PUT. So, your routes need to support both, which is what Rails does in the background via `resources :pairs` in config/routes.rb.

You shouldn't need to, if you're using default Rails conventions, override which HTTP verb is used for a given form submission.

And, if you want further insight into these issues, take a look at this SO question: 
[PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
<%= form_for pair do |f| %>
     <td><%= pair.token.value %></td>
     <td><%= pair.pair_token.value %></td>
     <td><%= pair.freq %></td>
     <td><%= pair.distance %></td>
     <td><%= f.select :distance, [['', nil], ['Strongly Opposite', -3], ['Moderately Opposite', -2], ['Weakly Opposite', -1],
                              ['No Relationship', 0], ['Weakly Similar', 1], ['Moderately Similar', 2], ['Strongly Similar', 3]], {}, {} %></td>
     <td><%= pair.agree %></td>
     <td><%= f.select :agree, [['', nil],['True', 1], ['False', 0]], {}, {} %></td>
     <td><%= f.submit %></td>
<% end %>
```

form_for knows how to handle create/update of the record, so there is no need to specify method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to include the token in the form like:

```
<%= form_for [:tokens, pair] do |f| %>
 <td><%= pair.token.value %></td>
 <td><%= pair.pair_token.value %></td>
 <td><%= pair.freq %></td>
 <td><%= pair.distance %></td>
 <td><%= f.select :distance, [['', nil], ['Strongly Opposite', -3], ['Moderately Opposite', -2], ['Weakly Opposite', -1],
                          ['No Relationship', 0], ['Weakly Similar', 1], ['Moderately Similar', 2], ['Strongly Similar', 3]], {}, {} %></td>
 <td><%= pair.agree %></td>
 <td><%= f.select :agree, [['', nil],['True', 1], ['False', 0]], {}, {} %></td>
 <td><%= f.submit %></td>
<% end %>
```

So your routes will be:

```
[POST] /tokens/:token_id/pairs/:pair_id
```

If that doesn't work try this one:

```
<%= form_for [@token, pair] do |f| %>
 <td><%= pair.token.value %></td>
 <td><%= pair.pair_token.value %></td>
 <td><%= pair.freq %></td>
 <td><%= pair.distance %></td>
 <td><%= f.select :distance, [['', nil], ['Strongly Opposite', -3], ['Moderately Opposite', -2], ['Weakly Opposite', -1],
                          ['No Relationship', 0], ['Weakly Similar', 1], ['Moderately Similar', 2], ['Strongly Similar', 3]], {}, {} %></td>
 <td><%= pair.agree %></td>
 <td><%= f.select :agree, [['', nil],['True', 1], ['False', 0]], {}, {} %></td>
 <td><%= f.submit %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't hard code method cause same form is being used in different actions and you are breaking Rails conventions.

```
@object = MyModel.new
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
```

same if you doing edit action

```
@object = MyModel.find(2)
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
```

rails will take care about method. Hope it helps !